# What is the TLS 1.3 Flag for DefaultSecureProtocols?

Tags: security, tls1.3

Microsoft article ["How to enable TLS 1.2 on client"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client) tells us to use the flag 0x00000800 in DefaultSecureProtocols under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp and HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp as part of enabling TLS 1.2.

What is the flag for TLS 1.3?

The pattern in Microsoft article ["Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392), illustrated below, implies that the flag would be 0x00002000.  However, I have not found documentation on this.

| DefaultSecureProtocols Value | Protocol enabled |
| --- | --- |
| 0x00000008 | Enable SSL 2.0 by default |
| 0x00000020 | Enable SSL 3.0 by default |
| 0x00000080 | Enable TLS 1.0 by default |
| 0x00000200 | Enable TLS 1.1 by default |
| 0x00000800 | Enable TLS 1.2 by default |

Answer (score 0):

The value for TLS 1.3  = 0x00002000

Comment: For the time being, I do not need to enable TLS 1.3, so I did not try to use x00002000.  Seb, did you get confirmation somewhere that the flag for TLS 1.3 is 0x00002000?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I had no confirmation whatsoever. However, I can confirm this flag works to enable TLS 1.3 from multiple tests I've made